# replace values in a String from a Hashtable in Java

Tags: java, hashtable

My string looks like;

```
String values = "I am from UK, and you are from FR";
```

and my hashtable;

```
Hashtable countries = new Hashtable();
countries.put("United Kingdom", new String("UK"));
countries.put("France", new String("FR"));
```

What would be the most effective way to change the values in my string with the values from the hashtable accordingly. These are just 2 values to change, but in my case I will have 100+

Comment: Just an "FYI" - why are you using `new String("UK")` instead of just `"UK"`? What difference do you think that will make?

Comment: Shouldn't the hashtable be the other way around? With the short names as the keys, since those are the ones you want to find the long names for.

Comment: Thanx @Jon Skeet I just c/p the lines and missed that part.
@Andrei Fierbinteanu you are right, my bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a whole lot you can do to optimize this in a way which is worthwhile. Actually you can construct an FSM for custom replacements like that but it's probably more than you want to really do.

```
Map<String, String> countries = new HashMap<String, String>();
countries.put("United Kingdom", "UK");
countries.put("France", "FR");
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : countries.entrySet()) {
  values.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

A couple of notes:

1. Don't use `Hashtable`. Use a `Map` (interface) and `HashMap` (class) instead;
2. Declare your variable, parameter and return types, where applicable, as interfaces not concrete classes;
3. Assuming you're using Java 5, use generic type arguments for more readable code. In this case, `Map<String, String>`, etc; and
4. Don't use `new String("UK")`. There is no need.

Comment: In this case, it should be `values.replace(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey())` because short names are values in the map. Although I don't know why it is so.

Comment: what's an FSM? (Google finds this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster) :-)

Answer (score 2):

Several thoughts. First of all: why use hashtable? hashmap is usually faster as hashtable is synchronized.

Then: why not use generics?

```
HashMap<String, String>
```

is much more expressive than just `HashMap`

Third: don't use `new String("UK")`, `"UK"` will do fine, you're creating the same string twice.

But to solve your problem, you probably want to turn the map around:

```
Map<String,String> countries = new HashMap<String, String>();
countries.put("UK", "United Kingdom");
countries.put("FR", "France");
```

Now if I understand you right you want to do something like this:

```
String values = "I am from UK, and you are from FR";
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : countries.entrySet()){
    values = values.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```